# Do not understand reason for compile error

Tags: ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Consider the following partial application in my new Hydro installation

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
//...
ros::start();
//...
}
```

when compiled with

```
g++  -I/opt/ros/hydro/include
```

I get the error: "undefined reference to 'ros::start()'"

There is no error about a missing include and I even included <ros/init.h> and got the same error.  I can see
ROSCPP_DECL void start();

Does anybody know why I get this compile error?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/134576/do-not-understand-reason-for-compile-error/) by [flb](https://answers.ros.org/users/8821/flb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 30 on 2014-02-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is a linker error. You will have to link against libroscpp.

**Edit**:

You might find these excellent tutorials by Jonathan Bohren useful. They explain step by step and bottom up how programs using ROS are built and how this is aided by catkin.

1. http://jbohren.com/articles/roscpp-hello-world/
2. http://jbohren.com/articles/gentle-catkin-intro/
3. http://jbohren.com/articles/modular-ros-packages/

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [flb](https://answers.ros.org/users/8821/flb/) on 2014-03-01**:
That was it, thanks.